# How to automate test cases in my website, which has more than 1000 different combinations

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to know what is the most efficient way to automate test cases related to filters where I will be seelcting different options from 3 different dropdowns, and hence they contribute to 100 plus combinations.

I am using selenium java for automation and I am using the BDD framework.

I tried scenario outline where in i gave each option in the parameters, but i dont think of it as an efficient way to test 1000 cases

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For front-end test you should pick up few combinations, let's say some most used. For testing all possible combinations there has to exist some back-end test.

Comment: Just adding, on @pburgr comment, Im not sure what you are trying to achieve by testing this, For UI test in my opinion you should test the functionality of the dropdowns, something like the ability to select a value etc. not sure why you would even have to test all the combinations on the back-end as well.